# Finding the column space and row space of matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this matrix

$A= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 2&  1 \\
0&1& 0&   -1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

which can be reduced to

$A= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2&  3 \\
0&1& 0&   -1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

The basis for the col A would be $(1,0),(2,1)$

the the basis of Row would be the non zero row of a reduced

$(1,0,2,3),(0,1,0,-1)$

But I am not sure if my row space is correct.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Note that you don't need to use the row-reduced rows for your basis, you can of course use the original rows (which correspond to the nonzero rows in your RREF).

Comment: Ok that makes sense thanks.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer I'm aware of the problem with unanswered problems. I just forgot about this post entirely. I actually expected OP to delete it. I'll answer it as Community.

Answer (score 1):

Turning my comment into an answer: Looks fine to me. Note that you don't need to use the row-reduced rows for your basis, you can of course use the original rows (which correspond to the nonzero rows in your RREF).